Flutter ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext!).settings.name is always `/`
I am new to Flutter, I don't know navigation much. I use the demo code in my application. I want to get the current RouterSettings.name so I can prevent duplicate router push, but ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext!)?.settings.name always return /. I know there is a couple of ways to prevent duplicate push, I'm just curious why it returns / and how to get the correct current RouterSettings. I hope someone can explain this :) Thank you!
Demo code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class Menu {
  /// Router settings name
  final String name;

  /// The menu title
  final String title;

  final IconData icon;

  bool selected;

  Widget Function(BuildContext)? _builder;

  Widget Function(BuildContext) get builder => _builder ?? (context) => ContentPage(title: title);

  set builder(Widget Function(BuildContext) b) => _builder = b;

  Menu({
    required this.name,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    this.selected = false,
    Widget Function(BuildContext)? builder,
  }) : _builder = builder;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Menu> menus = [
    Menu(name: '/', title: 'Dashboard', icon: Icons.dashboard, selected: true),
    Menu(name: '/Users', title: 'Users', icon: Icons.people),
    Menu(name: '/Orders', title: 'Orders', icon: Icons.list_alt),
    Menu(name: '/PersonalCentral', title: 'Mine', icon: Icons.person),
  ];
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey();

  void _onMenuTap(Menu m) {
    final currentName = ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext!)?.settings.name;
    debugPrint('_onMenuTap $currentName');
    //Issue is here, currentName is always `/`
    if (currentName == m.name) {
      // do not push repeatedly
      return;
    }
    navKey.currentState?.push(
      MaterialPageRoute(settings: RouteSettings(name: m.name), builder: m.builder),
    );
    setState(() {
      menus.where((m1) => m1.selected).firstOrNull?.selected = false;
      m.selected = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: ListView(
              children: menus.map(
                (m) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(m.icon),
                    title: Text(m.title),
                    selected: m.selected,
                    selectedColor: Theme.of(context).listTileTheme.selectedColor ?? Colors.lightBlue,
                    onTap: () => _onMenuTap(m),
                  );
                },
              ).toList(growable: false),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: Navigator(
              key: navKey,
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                // will print `onGenerateRoute /`
                debugPrint("onGenerateRoute ${settings.name}");
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                  settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/'),
                  builder: (context) => const ContentPage(title: 'Dashboard'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const ContentPage({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This demo code can be run in DartPad

This line is using context of navKey which is context of your _MyHomePageState and because your _MyHomePageState has RouterSettings.name is /, so as a result, currentName will be /
final currentName = ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext!)?.settings.name;

About prevent duplicate router push, I saw you already have selected in your Menu class, just use it simple like this:
  void _onMenuTap(Menu m) {
    if (m.selected) {
      return;
    }
    ...
  }


Thanks, you mean navKey.currentContext is context of _MyHomePageState?
How to get MaterialPageRoute(settings: RouteSettings(name: .name), builder: m.builder) router name, since it's pushed on the top, it's the current router of navKey.currentState, which context is  correct? ModalRoute.of(<which context?>). is it possible to get MaterialPageRoute(settings: RouteSettings(name: .name), builder: m.builder) router name in method _onMenuTap?

as far as I know, you can't get settings.name just by your navKey, because when you look inside NavigatorState class, it stores route list inside the private field _history
So if you want to get settings.name, you must call ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name; inside your ContentPage which has the right context
